# Get current language next-i18next

Tags: node.js, reactjs, internationalization, next.js, i18next

I am using NextJS with next-i18next. This is my home page:

```
import {withTranslation}  from '../config/next-i18next';

const Home = function Home() {
  return (<div>test</div>)
};

Home.getInitialProps = async () => {
  return {namespacesRequired: ['home']}
};

export default withTranslation('home')(Home);
```

What I want is to get current language inside a component/page, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 63):

`withTranslation` injects the `i18n` object.

```js
import {withTranslation}  from '../config/next-i18next';

const Home = function Home({ i18n }) {
  return (<div>{i18n.language}</div>)
  // ----------------^
};

Home.getInitialProps = async () => {
  return {namespacesRequired: ['home']}
};

export default withTranslation('home')(Home);
```

Or using Hooks,

```js
import {useTranslation}  from '../config/next-i18next';

const Home = function Home() {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation('home');
  return (<div>{i18n.language}</div>)
  // ----------------^
};

Home.getInitialProps = async () => {
  return {namespacesRequired: ['home']}
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 13):

With Next.js you could also use the [useRouter](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router) hook.

```
import {withTranslation}  from '../config/next-i18next';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Home = function Home() {
const router = useRouter()
const currentLang =  router.locale // => locale string eg. "en"
  return (<div>test</div>)
};

Home.getInitialProps = async () => {
  return {namespacesRequired: ['home']}
};

export default withTranslation('home')(Home);
```

Comment: It works only if you enable it modifying the next.config.js. 
You can enable max 100 "known" locales (I wanted to support any possible locale and I set it within 550 locales but it raise an error explaining there is this limit).
Also it changes your url to go always on a path within a locale, mysite.com/mypage/ -> mysite.com/en-US/mypage , a behaviour that maybe you don't want.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, @PMarc
Could you please share your code of `withTranslation` function?
It's not working from the box.